# Error on Active Directory Role Providers

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, active-directory

I've been working on this problem for a while and can't seem to find any solution that works... I am trying to get my active directory working on my project and I keep getting the following error. Maybe this is something simple that is just going right over my head. Does anyone have any advice on which direction to go with this?

Description: An error occurred during the processing of a configuration file required to service this request. Please review the specific error details below and modify your configuration file appropriately.

Parser Error Message: Could not load type 'ActiveDirectoryRoleProvider'.

Source Error:

```
Line 33:         <clear />
Line 34:         <add name="ActiveDirectoryRoleProvider" connectionStringName="ADConnectionString" connectionUsername="username"
Line 35:              connectionPassword="password" attributeMapUsername="sAMAccountName" type="ActiveDirectoryRoleProvider" />
Line 36:       </providers>
Line 37:     </roleManager>
```

Comment: Did you build a custom Role Provider for AD called ActiveDirectoryRoleProvider?

Comment: Working on that now... Not sure how to do it but I'm slowly getting there...

Answer (score 2):

If you've created your own ActiveDirectoryRole Provider, make sure the spelling of what you put on the name and type is the same with the name of the class, remove the namespace so it should resolve properly.

```
e.g. remove the namespace of the ff:

namespace yourproject.module {
public class ActiveDirectoryRoleProvider: RoleProvider
{ ... }

to make it appear
public class ActiveDirectoryRoleProvider: RoleProvider
```